# How to assign a value to a textbox at program start

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

i am creating a project for my class (C# in visual studio) that works as a token dispensing machine.

The user clicks on a button that changes the textbox with the label number of quarters from 0 to 1 and continues to increase that number by 1 each time the user clicks the button, the next textbox with the label number of tokens starts at 100 and decreases by 1 each time the user clicks the button mentioned above.

I have the code correct for the most of that, my question is how to get the textboxes to display the numbers 100 for number of tokens and 0 for the number of quarters when the program STARTS. Not when the button is clicked.

Comment: You need to flesh this question out more. Aside from asking your question more directly, you need to indicate the platform (Win forms, web forms, WPF, MVC, ???)

Comment: windows form application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple ways to accomplish this for a Win Forms application:

1. When the designer is open, select the given textbox and look at the Properties window. You'll see a property called Text, set it to your desired value.
2. In the code-behind for your form, in the constructor or `Form_Load` event, you can programmatically set the values using the form of `textBox.Text = "[DESIRED_VALUE]";`

Comment: in design mode Double click to your form and hope you will see Form_load @JordanKing